# Relationship between existence of OWFs and OWPs

Tags: one-way-function, permutation

OWPs are bijective OWFs, so every OWP is a OWF, but not the other way around.

However, I'm wondering what the relationship between the *existence* of both types of functions is. Obviously if one assumes OWPs to exist, OWFs will also exist.

But: Does the existence of OWFs imply the existence of OWPs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: "No".

The standard way to establish a statement of the form *if a primitive $B$ exists then another primitive $A$ also exists* is through a black-box reduction. This involves two steps:

1. Constructing an instance $\alpha$ of $A$ given black-box access to an instance $\beta$ of $B$ --- this is denoted by $\alpha^\beta$, where $\beta$ in the superscript refers to $\alpha$ having only oracle-access to $\beta$; and
2. Showing that $\alpha^\beta$ is hard to break assuming $\beta$ is --- this, in turn, is accomplished through a reduction algorithm $\mathcal{B}$ that breaks $\beta$ *given* an adversary $\mathcal{A}$ that breaks $\alpha$. ($\mathcal{B}$ only has black-box access to $\mathcal{A}$.)

Primitive $A$ is said to be *black-box-reduced* to primitive $B$. (Henceforth, by reduced, we mean black-box-reduced.)

Rudich showed$^*$ in his [PhD thesis](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/1988/CSD-88-468.pdf) that one-way permutations ($OWPs$) *cannot* be reduced to one-way functions ($OWFs$) --- i.e., given a $OWF$ $f$, one cannot construct a $OWP$ $\pi$ in the manner described above. In particular, what he showed is that Step 2 is not possible: i.e., there *cannot* exist a reduction algorithm $\mathcal{B}$ that breaks $f$ given an adversary $\mathcal{A}$ that breaks $\pi^f$.

Note that the above is a very strong statement: we are ruling out *all* reduction algorithms $\mathcal{B}$. One way to do this is through an "oracle separation".  What Rudich showed is that there exists an oracle $\mathcal{O}$ relative to which $OWFs$ exist, but any construction of OWP $\pi$ that uses $\mathcal{O}$ can be broken using an algorithm $\mathcal{A}^*$ that makes only a "few" (polynomially-many) queries to $\mathcal{O}$. The oracle $\mathcal{O}$ was chosen by Rudich as the random oracle, which is one-way with high probability -- in particular, it takes any algorithm "many" (nearly exponential) queries to a random oracle to invert it. The workings of $\mathcal{A}^*$ is a bit involved, but the high-level idea is it iteratively queries $\mathcal{O}$ on a "few" points in such a manner that it learns something new in every iteration. Since the implementation of $\pi$ is efficient, $\mathcal{A}^*$ can successfully invert $\pi$ using only a polynomial queries to $\mathcal{O}$. Note that $\mathcal{A}^*$ is only query-efficient, and runs in polynomial time only if it has access to a $\mathsf{PSPACE}$ oracle. But there is no way reduction $B$ could break the OWF ($\mathcal{O}$, i.e.) using $\mathcal{A}^*$ as the latter makes only a few queries to $\mathcal{O}$.

[Matsuda and Matsuura](https://www.iacr.org/archive/tcc2011/65970593/65970593.pdf) strengthened the above result to show that a $OWP$ cannot be reduced even to injective $OWFs$ (arguably the closest primitive to $OWPs$). §1.2 in that paper contains a more detailed (although still intuitive) explanation of the Rudich separation .

*P.S.* Oracle separations have been used extensively in cryptography. Some other examples are:

1. Public-key cryptography cannot be based on OWFs: [Impagliazzo and Rudich](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~russell/secret.ps)
2. Collision-resistant hash functions also cannot be based on OWFs: [Simon](http://www.mathmagic.cn/crypt1998-2003/papers/1403/14030334.pdf)

Other ways to rule out reductions are the so-called "[meta-reduction](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2002/23320268/coron.pdf)" technique and the [two-oracle](https://www.cs.bu.edu/~reyzin/papers/hash.pdf) technique. 
[Fischlin](http://www.cryptoplexity.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/media/crypt/publications_1/fischlinblack-box2012.pdf) has a nice exposition on these techniques: that should be a good starting point for further reading. You can read more about black-box reductions in [this](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/research/blackbox.pdf) paper by Trevisan, Reingold and Vadhan.

$^*$Rudich's result was modulo a conjecture, which was proved later by [Kahn et al.](http://www.uncg.edu/mat/faculty/cdsmyth/submission5.pdf).

Comment: How does this go together with the common practice of using a Feistel construction to build a permutation out of a function.

Comment: Feistel constructs a PRP out of a PRF. Are you asking what happens when one uses a OWF in place of the PRF?

Comment: Also, the Feistel construction is invertible.