# Collision Resistant Hashing from One-Way Functions?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, one-way-function

In general, can we construct a collision resistant hash function from a one-way function?

Comment: The constant function is also a one-way function.

Comment: @ratchetfreak No, it is most certainly not. For the constant function it is absolutely trivial to find preimages.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simon [Sim98] showed that is not possible to build a collision-resistant hash function from a one-way permutation (which is a stronger statement) in a *black-box* manner .

The main idea is to use the so-called *oracle-separation* technique. You can read more about it either [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/50083/relationship-between-existence-of-owfs-and-owps/50089#50089) or in this [survey](http://www.cryptoplexity.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/media/crypt/publications_1/fischlinblack-box2012.pdf).

[Sim98]: Daniel Simon. *Finding collisions on a one-way street: Can secure hash functions be based on general assumptions?* Eurocrypt'98.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference and the explanation!

Comment: What about the following construction. Apply the one way permutation to a different collision resistant hash function. Obviously cheating but I wonder how this doesn't violate the proof.

Comment: @MeirMaor Well, the way an oracle separation works makes sure that there is no hash function you could use in such a manner, unless it can be constructed from the OWP. Basically you introduce an oracle into the world that breaks all crypto. And in the next step you reintroduce a OWP as another oracle. All hash functions that may or may not exists in the real world are destroyed in the first step.