# Can one-way permutations be constructed from one-way functions?

Tags: one-way-function

We can construct various symmetric key primitives like PRGs, PRFs, SPRPs etc., assuming the existence of either one-way permutations or one-way functions with the former assumption allowing simpler constructions.

However, what is the relationship between one-way permutations and one-way functions? Clearly, the existence of one-way permutations implies the existence of one-way functions. Is the converse true? If it isn't then assuming one-way permutations is strictly stronger than assuming one-way functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was shown by Rudich in his PhD thesis [R] that it is not possible to construct one-way permutations (OWPs) from one-way functions (OWFs) in the framework of *black-box reductions*.$^1$ This was later strengthened by Matsuda and Matsura [MM], who ruled out black-box construction of OWPs from *injective* OWFs (which are much more structured than OWFs) that expand by even a single bit. So, yes assuming OWPs is strictly stronger than assuming OWFs (or iOWFs).

The technique employed in both the results is called *oracle separations*. The idea is to construct an oracle relative to which OWFs (or iOWFs) exist, but any black-box construction of one-way permutations is broken. An overview of Rudich's argument can be found on this [thread](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/50083/relationship-between-existence-of-owfs-and-owps/50089#50089).

But as Maeher points there could still exists [non-black-box constructions](https://www.boazbarak.org/Papers/thesis.pdf) of OWPs from OWFs. For example, we know that given indistinguishability obfuscation (IO), it is possible to construct (even trapdoor) OWPs from OWFs [BPW].$^2$ I believe a construction without IO is still open.

You can read more about the different notion of reductions [here](https://lucatrevisan.github.io/pubs/rtv04.pdf) and on black-box separations [here](https://www.cryptoplexity.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/media/crypt/publications_1/fischlinblack-box2012.pdf) and the references therein.

$^1$ This was under a conjecture which was later proved by Kahn et al. [KSS].

$^2$ There have been attempts at at ruling out even non-black construction of cryptographic objects from one-way functions (e.g, [DS]), but I am not sure if any of them extend to OWPs.

[BPW] Bitanksy, Paneth and Wichs, [Perfect Structure on the Edge of Chaos](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-662-49096-9_20), TCC 2016

[DS] Dachmann-Soled, Towards Non-Black-Box Separations ofPublic Key Encryption and One Way Function

[KSS] Kahn, Saks and Smyth, [A dual version of Reimer's inequality and a [enter link description here][5](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-662-49096-9_20)proof of Rudich's conjecture](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.143.532), CoCo 2000

[MM] Matsuda and Matsuura, [On Black-Box Separations among Injective One-Way Functions](https://www.iacr.org/archive/tcc2011/65970593/65970593.pdf), TCC 2011

[R] Rudich, [Limits on the Provable Consequences of One-way Functions](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/1988/6060.html), PhD Thesis

Comment: You could mention that *theoretically* non-black box techniques *could* potentially allow circumventing this impossibility result.